# URL is not Redirecting properly. (With IP address)

Tags: php, apache, magento, apache2

I have hosted my website (In Megento) in some hosting server. They said by default `mod_redirect` is enabled.

Problem is using IP address it doesn't redirect properly. I have not enter my host name in DNS.

See this is how it works now, If I request for some link from the URL

```
http://173.254.28.102/~finnande
```

It goes on like this

```
http://173.254.28.102/~finnande/~finnande/~finnande/~finnande/~finnande/~finnande/~finnande/~finnande/
```

Same problem one guy asked here, but no answer found

http://www.artio.net/support-forums/joomsef/community-support/joomsef-3/this-page-is-not-redirecting-properly

My .htaccess file contains...

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    RewriteBase /

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
```

Comment: We need the content of the .htaccess file to see what is going on there. That file will deceide how to redirect and it could be any number of things. You did however verify that it works if you dont use IP adres? For a simple test you could add it to your host file (on windows)

Comment: @Hugo Please check my .htaccess file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's problem with settings in .htaccess file and you should check lines with RewriteCond and RewriteRule directives.

Comment: Please check my .htaccess file, I have added the content.

Comment: I don't see any redirects in your htaccess file, probably a configuration problem in magento. Google put this up http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/magento/magento-redirect-loops/

Comment: Me again. I find a dozen different question all talking about infinite redirects in magento for different reasons. Apparently this is one thing magento does quite well :) I've searched for "Magento redirect loop" and "magento infinite loop"

Comment: I would change `RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase /~finnande`

Answer (score 0):

Answer "I would change RewriteBase / to RewriteBase /~finnande by  [`Krzysztof Księżyk`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1817915/krzysztof-ksiezyk)  works" .. Thanks  [Krzysztof Księżyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1817915/krzysztof-ksiezyk).